# Where i can to find material about Diffeomorphism Groups as Metric Spaces

Tags: lie-groups, fluid-dynamics

My professor give me one document where it speak about Diffeomorphism Groups as Metric Spaces
but it does no has calculations and i need to explain something about it.(The reference book is The Geometric of infinite-dimensional Groups, Boris, A and Robert Went) When i research in google do not appear many information, it seems is an actual subject. I would appreciate any help with references please, i am in Brazil, perhaps somebody in other continent has more access to another platforms or something, thank you a lot

Comment: Check [this](http://www.math.toronto.edu/khesin/papers/densities_diffeos7.pdf) paper.

Comment: thank you @Moishe Kohan